# FastPdfKit Warnings

Tags: objective-c, xcode, warnings

I am using the FastPdfKit framework, which itself is very good. Unfortunately, it's generating 74 warnings as a result of the developer not caring enough. I have contacted the developer, and received no help.

Here is a small sample of the warnings I am receiving:

```
(null): warning: (armv7) /Users/nick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FastPdfKit-fzecbtvxoxzaebbvelxsxcphcrom/Build/Intermediates/FastPdfKit.build/Release-iphoneos/FastPdfKit.build/Objects-normal/armv7/WebBrowser.o unable to open object file

(null): warning: (armv7) /Users/nick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FastPdfKit-fzecbtvxoxzaebbvelxsxcphcrom/Build/Intermediates/FastPdfKit.build/Release-iphoneos/FastPdfKit.build/Objects-normal/armv7/ReaderViewController.o unable to open object file

(null): warning: (armv7) /Users/nick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FastPdfKit-fzecbtvxoxzaebbvelxsxcphcrom/Build/Intermediates/FastPdfKit.build/Release-iphoneos/FastPdfKit.build/Objects-normal/armv7/OutlineViewController.o unable to open object file

(null): warning: (armv7) /Users/nick/Workspaces/MobFarm/git/FastPdfKitSample/FPKCore/libFastPdfKit.a(AudioStreamer.o) unable to open object file

(null): warning: (armv7) /Users/nick/Workspaces/MobFarm/git/FastPdfKitSample/FPKCore/libFastPdfKit.a(MFPDFOutline.o) unable to open object file
```

My name is James, and so the directory my project is in is actually Users/James/Developer. This Nick guy is the developer, and he couldn't care less. How could I go about removing these, or brute force hiding these specific warnings. I want to avoid hiding any other warnings I may need to see in the future.

Thank you.

Comment: What in particular did you do to get these errors? I don't get them when compiling the "kiosk" example from the download.

Comment: I followed the instructions on the website perfectly. Multiple times. I even did things differently, like the cleaning their build, and rebuilding, then including it.

Nothing has worked.

Comment: I see the problem now - it's just when building for device and not simulator. Trying to think of the best fix.

Comment: Careful with this framework, it's all good until you need some support. All you need to do is check their support forum to see how much they care (and yes we did have a commercial license). You've been warned :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Project > Build Settings > Build Options > Debug Information Format select DWARF instead of DWARF with dSYM File.

Comment: This works, but I don't think it's the best solution. It'll mean no dSYM is created, which is not ideal as it's used to symbolicate crash reports.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue today when creating a framework.

It seemed that no matter what I did building the framework I would get these kind of warnings when including it in another project.

The way I solved this was trial and error and to be honest I still do not understand what is going on.

Firstly in Xcode (4.5 for me) edit schemes, select Run and change build configuration to Release. (You can leave Debug Information Format to DWARK with dSYM File and you want to so you can symbolcate crash logs)

Click Run on the Tool bar (note command+R or Product - Run are disabled).

Then once built, right click framework in products and show in finder.

Choose the framework in the Build/Products/Release-iphoneos folder.

Should now not have these warnings.

If anyone knows what is going on here please share!